# cant login to phpmyadmin online using db4free.net

Tags: java, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

i try to use db4free for my project but when i create new account and try to login it still get that error :

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'aiko'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

thanks ..

Comment: did you find a solution? I am hitting this exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

Reset your password (if possible). Access Denied is usually either password failed, or the account doesn't exist at all.

If this persists, contact db4free.net about it.

Comment: i try to reset new pass but its impossible and get me (The user has not yet confirmed the verification mail.), they even didt send confirm the registration to my email .  its just look like this site is not work , what i do wrong ?